# Find the original dimension of the rectangle

Tags: geometry

A rectangle is 4 times as long as it is wide. If the length is increased by 4 inches and the width is decreased by 1 inch, the area will be 60 square inches. What were the dimensions of the original rectangle? Explain your answer.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. Do not use expressions like: "explain your answer". We are not here to do your homework but are eager to teach you some maths.

Comment: if the "inches" is troubling you, note that all the dimensions are in inches and hence for this problem you can drop it.  You must know that area of a rectangle = (length) x (width)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Denote its original width by $x$ and find an expression in $x$ for the area of the reformed rectangle. It should equalize $60$ so...

Comment: so it'll be like 60=lw 60=(4w+4)(w-1) cause the length is 4x the width and they added 4 to the "new length" then it's w-1 cause they deducted 1 from the "new width".  Is my equation right or am I in the wrong path?

Comment: Your equation is correct. The second step is to solve it. Keep in mind that $w$ cannot be negative here.

Comment: Okay I think I got it w=4?

Comment: That is correct. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

$$\ Width=a, Length=4a , $$
$$\text {so the total original area is: }\ A=4a^2$$
$$\text {now we know that the new area is}$$
$$\ A'=(4a+4)(a-1)=4a^2-4a+4a-4=4a^2-4=60$$
$$\text{so }\ 4a^2=A=64$$
$$\ a^2=64/4=16$$
$$\ a=4$$
$$\text{so}\ Width=4\text{ and }\ Length=16$$
$$\text{(all expressed in inches)}$$

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, but the OP was asked for the *dimensions* of the original rectangle. Not explicitly for its area.

Comment: sorry, just edited now